# Social worker from Earth drawn into galactic war between two planets, one of which is female dominated

Tags: story-identification, novel

I have been looking for a novel that I read in the 90s that I can't remember the name of it or the author! It's about a social worker from Earth who accidentally gets drawn into a galactic war between two planets, one of which is run by a female dominated society. The main characters are the female social worker and 2 male alien peacekeepers who wear amulets that are alive and give them special abilities. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's what you are looking for, but your description shares some similarities with [World Without Stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Without_Stars) (a french graphic novel, I have seen the translation *The Land Without Stars* for the title too) from the *Valérian and Laureline* series:

- The two main protagonists, Valérian and Laureline, are humans sent from Earth and are trying to restore peace between two societies. One dominated by women, the other one by men. But both societies live on the same planet (*inside* the same planet, actually).
- They don't have amulets with special abilities, but in *Empire of a Thousand Planets*, they encounter people using some kind of bugs as living jewels.